# Improving React app runtime performance using Chrome's dev tools analyzer

Tags: reactjs, webpack, optimization, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to improve runtime performance but I am having a hard nut to crack trying to understand the used/unused piece of code highlight tool in Chrome's dev tools.

From what I understand, we should aim to 100% of green area which indicates what percentage of the loaded code is being used on the given screen. The significant red part means we load code which is redundant as we don't use it.

[image]

Now, I think did pretty much everything composition wise to e.g. not include components which are not needed on the given screen but the max I squeezed is 66%/33% of used/unused code

[image]

What intrigues me is that when I inspect bundle.js I see common odd pattern of highlighting:

- the function definition gets green mark
- but the function body gets red mark

It happens for ordinary util functions and also for SVG files. What's importany to emphasise, it happens for the functions that I am 100% sure are not used in the analyzed screen.

Does anyone know what it happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have maybe barrel files? (a file reexporting all of your SVGs/util functions)

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie yes, I do have a couple of these but I don't think it causes the issue (yet it was also one of the things I was suspecting causing it). 

Just spent 20 minutes to fix around 150 imports after removing them and the red mark still says 33%

Comment: By default webpack considers all modules to have side effects, so if you import only one icon from a barrel file that reexport 100 icons, Webpack will import all 100 icons just in case there are side effects in those files.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie then again - why don't I see this being reflected in used/unused ratio after removing all barrel files?

Comment: Are you looking at the used/unused using a dev build? It still looks rather readable. I Haven't used webpack in a while, but tree-shaking use to be done as part of the minification phase which by default is only run for prod builds. It's possible that the tree shaking will improve this ratio.

Comment: Can you provide more source code? There isn't much to go off of at the moment. If you're able to recreate the issue in an example, that would also be viable.